# I am trying to build a query with more than 3 tables where data is scattered across

Tags: mysql, join

Table `tblSubject`

| subId | subName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mathematics |
| 2 | English |

---

Table `tblTeachers`

| teacherId | teacherName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jean |
| 2 | Mary |

---

Table `tblStudent`

| studentId | studentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Edward |
| 2 | Lauren |

---

Table `tblStudentSubMap`

| Id | studentId | teacherId | subId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

---

I am trying to get the below output but unable to with various inner joins etc

Attempted query:

```
SELECT tblsubject.subname, tblTeachers.teacherName 
  FROM tablesubject, tblteachers 
WHERE tblStudentSubMap.studentId=1
```

The `WHERE` condition input should be `studentid` and the corresponding subject name and teacher name should be returned.

Output

| id | tablesubject | teacherName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mathematics | Jean |
| 2 | English | Mary |

for Studentid = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various method on joining tables but you can try my below code

```
//Get columnName in every Table
SELECT map.Id,s.studentName,t.teacherName,sub.subName
FROM tblStudentSubMap map
LEFT JOIN tblStudent s ON s.studentID = map.studentID//Find Data with the same ID
LEFT JOIN tblTeacher t ON t.teacherID = map.teacherID//Find Data with the same ID
LEFT JOIN tblSubject sub ON sub.ID = map.subID;//Find Data with the same ID
```

Comment: Awesome Cyrille. Exact output as I wanted. Take care

Comment: Well, you can accept my answer if that solves your concern.

Comment: Cyrille Can you have a quick look at this thread please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162739/group-by-php-mysql-and-aggregate