# Group by - php mysql and aggregate

Tags: php, mysql, group

I am trying to display group by and aggregate using PHP and mysql. I am only able to group by. But not able to aggregate. Any help appreciated.

### Desired output

| Category#1 | - |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | candle1 |
| 2 | candle2 |
| 3 | candle3 |
| . | Total Qty = 55 |

| Category #2 | . |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stand1 |
| 2 | stand2 |
| 3 | stand3 |
| . | Total Qty = 45 |

| Category #3 | . |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cart1 |
| . | Total Qty = 5 |

### Current output

| Category #1 |
| --- |
| candle1 |
| candle2 |
| candle3 |

| Category #2 |
| --- |
| stand1 |
| stand2 |
| stand3 |

| Category #3 |
| --- |
| cart1 |

### Below is my current code

```
'<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblgroup order by id";  
$result2= $conn->query($query);
$options=""; 
$current_cat = null;
echo'<option value="">--Select Term--</option>';
//echo'<option value=all>All</option>';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){   

if ($row["productid"] != $current_cat) {
$current_cat = $row["productid"];
echo "Category #{$current_cat}<br>";
}
echo $row["productname"] . "<br>";
}
?> '
```

### Below is the DML

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tblgroup` (
      `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `productid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `productname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `qty` int(50) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### --
Data for table tblgroup

```sql
    INSERT INTO `tblgroup` (`id`, `productid`, `productname`, `qty`) VALUES
    ('1', '1', 'candle1', 10),
    ('2', '1', 'candle2', 20),
    ('3', '1', 'candle3', 25),
    ('4', '2', 'stand1', 15),
    ('5', '2', 'stand2', 25),
    ('6', '2', 'stand3', 5),
    ('7', '3', 'cart1', 30);
```

Comment: could you please let us know, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Saroj, I am trying to get a group by with aggregate result in php

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).